# Angular object properties change tracking (EF Core change tracking like)

Tags: angular, typescript, change-tracking

I'm searching a way to get a change tracking on single properties of and Object array. Something like EntityFramework is able to do when is handling entities. For Example:

We get a list of Person from api that is the "base version of the collection"

```
class Person {
 name: string;
 age: number;
}
```

```
let list = [ {John, 23}, {Elen, 45}, ...];
```

and when we something is change have the possibility to easily get that something was changed

```
list[1].age = 35;

//and have the possibility to do something like:
  let changes = list.detachChange(); //changes.modified return [{Elen, 45}]

//or extract a true false value if something was changed.
 boolean changed = list.hasChanges; // return true
```

I'm just asking if there is already something that can help or that implements this behaviour in Angular world.
The final purpose should be for example display elements in a list and when an element is changed change the color of that element and enable the possibility to save the page, and also if changed back to original state so on the list there are no changes disable save button. This is the final purpose, maybe there are better design for this situation and I would appreciate any kind of support